# Как передать переменные с телефона в ардуино через блютуз без установки софта

Tags: wifi, arduino, bluetooth

Сразу озвучу цель - нужно чтобы любой пользователь мог подключить мою ардуину к своему Wi-Fi роутеру, используя свой телефон без всякого софта, т.е. передать ssid/pass роутера через блютуз, например.

В ардуино делаю первые шаги.

Сделал веб-сервер - [отсюда](http://digitrode.ru/computing-devices/mcu_cpu/1570-esp32-veb-server-s-pomoschyu-arduino-ide.html). Работает. Но.

Для подключения ардуины к Wi-Fi роутеру надо указать ssid/pass ещё до стадии прошивки.

Вопрос: Как передать ssid/pass на уже прошитую ардуину? Блютузом же можно подключиться с любого телефона. А дальше как?

Comment: Сделайте "кнопку настройки", нажав на которую при включении ESP запускается как точка доступа, зайдя на которую записываете нужные параметры (ssid, pass и пр.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Довольно простой способ сделать конфигурацию параметров wifi через режим точки доступа, как уже порекомендовали в комментариях.

Можно делать вручную или, что проще, воспользоваться библиотекой [AutoConnect](https://hieromon.github.io/AutoConnect/gettingstarted.html). Она хранит ssid и пароль и при включении пробует их использовать чтобы присоединиться к точке wifi. Если это не удается, то ESP32 переходит в режим точки доступа и тогда можно присоединиться с телефона и там настроить ssid и пароль. После этого они запоминаются и ESP32 их использует в дальнейшем.

Код выглядит так:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <AutoConnect.h>

WebServer Server;
AutoConnect      Portal(Server);

void rootPage() {
  char content[] = "Hello, world";
  Server.send(200, "text/plain", content);
}

void setup() {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();

  Server.on("/", rootPage);
  if (Portal.begin()) {
    Serial.println("WiFi connected: " + WiFi.localIP().toString());
  }
}

void loop() {
    Portal.handleClient();
}
```